# Change color scheme for site belonging to hub in modern SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme, hub-site, spcolor

I'm new to Sharepoint online and have a hub with several sites that should share the same hub navigation etc. However, for reasons of user experience, each site belonging to the hub should get its own color scheme.

By default, this seems to be prohibited. Going to `Settings -> change design`, it tells me (roughly translated from German)

> "Your website is connected to the hub website XXX and is bound to use the hub's design."

After some googling I followed a hint and tried setting the design via the classic website settings. This even worked for a minute or two but then the hub color scheme appeared, again.

I also tried setting the color schemes via powershell using Set-SPOWebTheme. This gave me a (quite unspecific) error.

Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No.

We cannot disable Hub Site theme inheritance.

Per my test, changing the classic appearance has no effect on modern pages. I also tried to use powershell to change the theme of the associated site, but after a few minutes it will be converted to the hub site theme.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL= "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing"
 
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credential (Get-Credential) #-UseWebLogin
 
#Change Set Theme
Set-PnPTheme -ColorPaletteUrl "/_catalogs/theme/15/palette008.spcolor" -BackgroundImageUrl "/_layouts/15/images/image_bg008.jpg" -FontSchemeUrl "/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme003.spfont"
```

More information for your reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/sharepoint-online-change-site-theme-using-powershell.html